# Counting the number of overall entries from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ranking

I am trying to rank my users by the number of entries they have submitted to 2 different tables.

table gvr:

```
rid | jid 
---------------
1     54
2     54
3     54
4     75
5     75
```

table gos:

```
sid | jid
---------------
1     54
2     54
3     75
4     75
5     23
6     23
```

Desired results:

```
jid | overall_cnt | gvr_cnt | gos_cnt
----------------------------------
54    5            3          2
75    4            2          2
23    2            0          2
```

I have:

```
(SELECT jid, count(*) gvr_count
FROM gvr 
WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY jid)
UNION ALL 
(SELECT jid, count(*) gos_count
FROM gos
WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY jid)
```

But this is grossly incorrect. I have been searching for through other posts similar to my situation but could not find anything of too much value yet. I am thinking of off loading the data manipulation onto PHP, but it would be convenient to do it in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated Gordon answer this is the best approach.

```
 select jid ,sum(gvr_count)+ sum(gos_count) as OverallCount ,
  sum(gvr_count) as gvr_count, sum(gos_count) as gos_count
   from ((SELECT jid, count(*) gvr_count, 0 as gos_count
   FROM gvr 
   WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY jid
  )
  UNION ALL 
  (SELECT jid, 0 as gvr_count, count(*) gos_count
   FROM gos
   WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY jid
  )
 ) t
group by jid
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is pretty close.  You want the `union all` and then to do a `group by`:

```
select jid, sum(gvr_count) + sum(gos_count) as Overall_Count,
        sum(gvr_count) as gvr_count, sum(gos_count) as gos_count
from ((SELECT jid, count(*) gvr_count, 0 as gos_count
       FROM gvr 
       WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY jid
      )
      UNION ALL 
      (SELECT jid, 0 as gvr_count, count(*) gos_count
       FROM gos
       WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY jid
      )
     ) t
group by jid
```

I think this is the best approach in MySQL to ensure that you get all "jid"s, even those that are only in one table.

Comment: I missed the condition you mentioned in your note after the query :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT temp.jid,gvr_cnt + gos_cnt as totals,temp.*
FROM
(
SELECT gos1.jid
,(SELECT COUNT(*) from gvr where gvr.jid = gvr1.jid) AS gvr_cnt
,(SELECT COUNT(*) from gos where gos.jid = gos1.jid) AS gos_cnt
FROM gos gos1 left join gvr gvr1 on gos1.jid = gvr1.jid
group by gos1.jid
  ) as temp
group by temp.jid
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/117109/27)

Comment: is there anything that would break this query on mysql? Cause it works in sqlfiddle. but I am having trouble getting it to work on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be fully correct but I hope you can take it from here:

```
SELECT innerQuery_1.jid AS jid, 
       (innerQuery_1.gvr_count + innerQuery_2.gos_count) AS overall_cnt, 
       innerQuery_1.gvr_count AS gvr_count,
       innerQuery_2.gos_count AS gos_count
FROM   (SELECT jid, count(*) gvr_count
        FROM   gvr 
        WHERE  jid IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY jid) AS innerQuery_1,
       (SELECT jid, count(*) gos_count
        FROM   gos
        WHERE jid IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY jid) AS innerQuery_2
GROUP BY innerQuery_1.jid
```

Comment: it is not returning jid 23